# Distinguishing among classification, typology, taxonomy, and ontology?

Tags: meaning, terminology

I recently wrote a thesis applying archaeological typology to art attribution. In the process, it became clear that disparate disciplines share analogous debates regarding classification. I'd like to hear more from diverse perspectives. Given that classification as a process is itself a form of definition, it seems appropriate to ask:

> What are the differences among [a] *classification*, *typology*, *taxonomy*, and *ontology*?

Initially, let's assume that each of these refers not to the *process(es)* of classification (etc.), but to the results of these processes, i.e. to *categories* rather than *categorization*. However, I'm leaving the question open-ended: approach the subject as you wish!

I'm particularly interested in seeing a set of answers that represents a variety of disciplines. Answers that cite dictionaries or common usage are welcome, but I'm far more interested in the "jargon" side of things. Please don't feel obliged to cover multiple disciplines in one answer – in this case, focusing on one discipline in-depth is better than skimming over many disciplines without detail. Overall, partial answers are acceptable (e.g. typology vs. taxonomy) so long as that specific issue is discussed in sufficient depth.

Comment: I'll add an answer presenting a perspective from archaeological typology soon, but I'd like to wait a bit so as to not predispose other answers.

Comment: And don't forget *ontology*.

Comment: @Drew: Good call! Edited. I'm worried about making this question too broad, but adding _ontology_ seems very appropriate to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

> *classification, typology, taxonomy, ontology*

***Classification*** is a very general term, not a linguistic one. At least it has no special linguistic meaning, though the process of sorting things into classes is common in all linguistics. Which classes and how they're organized varies widely.

***Ontology*** is also not a linguistic term, but a philosophical one. It's just the Greek for 'words about things' (*ontos* = thing; *logos* = word), and it is the study of what kinds of "things" there are (and often how they should be classified). It's one of the things that lexical semanticists hafta know, just like syntacticians hafta know logic. [Here's a sample ontology](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cutting.pdf) from a lexical semantics class.

***Taxonomy*** is a term from biology. A *taxon* is a grouping of related species, like a family of plants (e.g, Asteraceae), a species of ape (Homo sapiens), a phylum of trees (Gingkoales), etc. The plural is *taxa* (it's a Greek neuter noun), and *taxonomy* is the study and application of various types of classification (originally strictly by physical traits, but now almost always by genomic properties -- which has left biological taxonomy topsy-turvy for some years).

Linguists use the term *taxonomy* to refer to historical linguistics. We talk about the taxonomy of the Indo-European language family, for instance. Is the Balto-Slavic branch more closely related to the Indo-Iranian branch, thereby forming a "satem" branch in contrast to a "centum" branch? Or not? The argument's been going on for a century or so, and most of us don't think so. But some still do. Historical linguistics takes a long time. So taxonomy in biology is pretty much a metaphor (but a useful one) in linguistics.

***Typology***, finally, is definitely a linguistic specialty. It means, in a way, the opposite of being historically related. We say that English and German are related -- they're in the same taxon -- but they're not typologically similar at all. German is a highly inflected language (aka 'synthetic'), whereas English has practically no inflections at all, and does everything with syntactic constructions instead. This is called an "analytic" or "isolating" language. German resembles Hindi and Turkish in this typological regard, while English resembles Vietnamese and Mandarin. [See WALS](https://wals.info/) for more details on what kinds of typological features languages have (or lack).

Comment: Ontology has a different (and broader) meaning in philosophy than it does in linguistics; [see the SEP.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ontology/#Onto)

Comment: Right. And in philosophy classes, it's usually paired with epistemology, for obvious reasons.

Comment: In western philosophy, **ontology** concerns itself with the nature of beings, and while it involves classification, it isn't classification of abstractions but of existential entities.

Comment: It's odd, though, how there are always abstract classifications available for existential entities.